# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException while reading user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read values from a user with Scanner with the data types of the inputs as follows:

```
int
String
String
String
int
```

but I keep getting this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)

at Solution.main(Solution.java:22)
```

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    int i= sc.nextInt();
    String c = sc.next();
    String e = sc.next();
    String f = sc.next();
    int g = sc.nextInt();
}
```

What could be causing this inside my while loop?

Comment: Is your input you've provided a sample input, or is there always 5 elements in the order you've stated? If so, you don't need that while loop as it will try to read a 6th element but the exception seems to be coming from one of the calls to next(). Can you provide a complete and running example instead? It's very hard to understand the full context with an incomplete fragment.

Comment: @DickChesterwood The data can change in 5's. Perhaps one input has 10, another has 25, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to answer this as it seems that you are trying to read from a file, but the code is built to read from the console.

Comment: // If we are at the end of input then NoSuchElement;
    // If there is still input left then InputMismatch

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
  int i= sc.nextInt();
  String c = sc.next();
  String e = sc.next();
  String f = sc.next();
  int g = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: won't this result in an infinite while loop

Comment: Yes, but same is what you were achieving from the previous code also

Comment: Or at a specific condition, you can break out of the loop using a break statement or can have a boolean variable in while condition

Answer (score 0):

You can just get rid of the while loop, unless you want to continue taking those inputs but it will keep running until you give it invalid input (it will run infitely).

Try this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
String c = sc.next();
String e = sc.next();
String f = sc.next();
int g = sc.nextInt();
// print out all use input
System.out.println(i + " " + c + " " + e + " " + f + " " + g);
```